# slideUp()/slideDown() not working correctly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, slide

I'm having trouble coding the following. In my view, I dynamically create a list of "li" elements for each credit card. Each li item contains a delete button, that when clicked, adds attribute "display:block" to the li item and then trigger a slidedown effect. Then I want to slideup div called "removethis" to show message "Are you sure you want to remove, with YES,NO options"

My problem is, everytime I click a remove button, the effect always occur on the very first li item, not the li item which I selected to remove. I'm not sure how to code this correctly in jquery. I tried playing around with traversing but didnt get anywhere.

```
 @if (Model.Cards != null && Model.Cards.Count > 0)
{
    <h2>Your linked cards</h2>

<ol class="payu_creditcard_list">
        @foreach (var card in Model.Cards)
        {
            var subLogoClass = string.Empty;
            switch (card.fields.information)
            {
                case "Master Card":
                    subLogoClass = "mastercard";
                    break;
                case "Visa":
                    subLogoClass = "visa";
                    break;
                case "American Express":
                    subLogoClass = "amex";
                    break;
                case "Diners Club":
                    subLogoClass = "dinersclub";
                    break;
                case "Samba":
                    subLogoClass = "samba";
                    break;
                case "b-Smart":
                    subLogoClass = "bsmart";
                    break;
            }

            <li>
                <div id="creditCardDetails">
                    <a class="payu_creditcard_remove" href="#">Remove</a>
                    <div class="payu_creditcard_logo  @subLogoClass">@card.fields.information</div>
                    <div class="payu_creditcard_number">@card.fields.card_number</div>
                    <div class="payu_creditcard_expiry"><span class="payu_accompanying_text">Expires: </span><span class="payu_creditcard_expirydate">@(string.Format("{0}/{1}", card.fields.card_expiry.Substring(0, 2), card.fields.card_expiry.Substring(4)))</span></div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="payu_creditcard_description">@card.fields.description</div>
                </div>

                <div id="confirmDelete" style="display: none">
                    <div class="confirm_message">Are you sure?</div>
                    <div class="confirm_buttons">
                        <button class="btn btn-submit btn-full">Yes</button>
                        <a href="#">No</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
    }
</ol>
}
```

**And here is my JS:**

```
    $(".payu_creditcard_remove").click(function () {
    $("#confirmDelete").attr("display", "block");
    $("#confirmDelete").slideDown("500");
    $("#creditCardDetails").slideUp("500");
});
```

**UPDATE**

I've ended up using the following, but its still not perfect, when I select an li item, all divs seem to move slightly.

```
$(".payu_creditcard_remove").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

$("ol.payu_creditcard_list li").find("#confirmDelete").slideUp("1500");
$("ol.payu_creditcard_list li").find("#creditCardDetails").slideDown("1500");

$(this).parent().next().show();
$(this).parent().slideUp("1500");
$(this).parent().next().slideDown("1500");
```

});

Comment: Since there are multiple `li`, using `id` is not ideal because ids are unique, use `class` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
$(".payu_creditcard_remove").click(function () {
    $(".shown").hide();
    $(this).parent().next().addClass("shown").show();
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown("500");
    $(this).parent().slideUp("500");
});
```

Comment: The above solution works, but after selecting delete on another li item, the previous selected li item still has the div that "Are you sure you want to delete" open. How would I go about reseting the previous slidedown effects so that only the newly selected on is displayed.

Comment: Mmm, doesn't complete works, it completely hides the li item. See before: http://i59.tinypic.com/of8s9t.png and after http://i58.tinypic.com/28hzby9.png